# Feature request - notification of new version of file

Tags: google-drive-api, slack-api

I use Google Drive with Slack. I get notified in Slack if a new file is added to a folder on Google Drive in the folder that is shared with me. I would like to get notified when someone uploads a new version of a file that already exists in a folder that is shared with me.

Slack support says that this not supported by the Google Drive API.

If this is true, please add this to list of feature requests.

If this is false, please show me where I can find this in the Google Drive API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to request this idea to the Google team. In that case you should report it at [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) as a feature request, where it will be reviewed and assessed by googlers. Please, ask me any additional doubt about the procedure.

Comment: Thank you. This is the information I was hpoing soeone would give me.